# Why is there no difference in output for the below code?

Tags: java, this

I am pretty new to java and getting confused with the below code:

```
public class NewNode {
    NewNode next = null;
    int data;

    public NewNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addToNode(int data){
        NewNode n = this;
        System.out.println(n);
        NewNode newlyCreated = new NewNode(data);
    }
}
```

but even after changing the `addToNode` method as below:

```
    public void addToNode(int data){
                NewNode newlyCreated = new NewNode(data);
                NewNode n = this;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
```

The output of n doesn't change . If,`this` keyword refers to the current instance of the object then shouldn't `newlyCreatedNode` be the output in the second scenario.Please help....

Comment: No!!! Why should it? `this` is the current instance, it does not matter if you just create new instance of _something_ somewhere around the usage of `this`, `this` refers to the object you are currently operating in.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [doc tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html?PHPSESSID=928a65f55b2980c1d48e2eeb584d0c39):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.

So in both example `this` refers to the *object you call `addToNode()` on*. The fact that you create an object within the method is irrelevant. So:

```
public void addToNode(int data){
    NewNode n = this;  //Refers to the object this method is called on
    System.out.println(n);
    NewNode newlyCreated = new NewNode(data);  //Creates a random object
}

public void addToNode(int data){
      NewNode newlyCreated = new NewNode(data);  //Creates a random object
      NewNode n = this;   //Refers to the object this method is called on
      System.out.println(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is the current instance i.e. the instance that invokes the `addNode` method.
Thus when you create a new Node by `NewNode newlyCreated = new NewNode(data);` it just creates a new Node locally. The current instance(i.e. `this`) remains the same.

Your output will change if you do `this.data = data` i.e. changing the `data` field of current instance

***EDIT:*** Also you need to override the toString method to print `NewNode` otherwise it'll print default `Object`'s `toString` method

Comment: *"Your output will change if you do this.data = data i.e. changing the data field of current instance"* - only if `toString()` is overwritten.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes of course. This is assumed :) I'll update it

Answer (score 2):

Okay, take a look at this piece of code. Let me try to give you a simpler example.

Assume that we have a class like this:

```
class A {
    int data;

    void printData() {
        System.out.println(this.data);
    }
}
```

And then you create two instances of A like this:

```
A a1 = new A(); a1.data = 10;
A a2 = new A(); a2.data = 12;
```

So there are now two objects `a1` and `a2` which are of the `A` type.

Now let's call the `printData()` method on them. How would you do it?

```
a1.printData();
a2.printData();
```

Now look at the first print call, it is happening on the `a1` object. So now control goes into the `printData` method, where the `this` will resolve to `a1`, so `this.data` will be same as `a1.data` from outside.

Now in the second call, yes you get it right. It is being invoked on `a2` object, so inside the method `printData`, `a2` will be assigned to `this`.

This is what it means when they say that *`this` resolves to the current object.*

Got it now?